# How do I get the block under the player?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I want to know which block is under the Player .And if the BLock is identical to another block (selected before), do something.
i tried something like this: (But I know it doesn't work at all). Thank you!

```
BlockPos PlayerIsStandingOn = player.getPosition().down();
Block PlayerIsStandingOnBlock = worldIn.getBlockState(PlayerIsStandingOn);
if (PlayerIsStandingOn == randomBlock) { }
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". Does it fail to compile? Does it compile but then throw an exception at runtime? Does it run without failure but always take the true path, or always take the false path?

Comment: Hello Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, it doesn't work at all, it has 3 Errors and when I fix one Error another Error appears…  So I think I have to do it completely differently... But I don't know how.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error text.

Comment: okay so heres my Code (I've reworked it a bit) `BlockPos PlayerIsStandingOn = player.getPosition().down();
   BlockState PlayerIsStandingOnBlock = worldIn.getBlockState(PlayerIsStandingOn);
   if (PlayerIsStandingOn == randomBlock)     
   {  } `   And the Error is :" Incompatible operand types BlockPos and Block" But when I change it, there are several Errors (Thanks for your Help!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close but `getBlockState` returns `IBlockState` not `Block`. You could do it like this:

```
BlockPos posBelow = player.getPosition().down();
IBlockState blockStateBelow = player.world.getBlockState(posBelow);
```

then you can either check if the block is a specific material like so, I think this is likely what you're after; this will return if the Material is not `GROUND` (dirt):

```
if(blockStateBelow.getMaterial() != Material.GROUND)
    return;
//your logic here
```

Or you can do a comparison to check if two blocks are the same:

```
if(!Block.isEqualTo(blockStateBelow.getBlock(), <your other block>))
    return;
//your logic here
```

And so on...

### Edit

This answer was originally written for 1.12.2, it seems a few things have changed in 1.15.2

```
BlockPos posBelow = player.getPosition().down();
BlockState blockStateBelow = player.world.getBlockState(posBelow);
Block below = blockStateBelow.getBlock();

if(!below.equals(<your other block>))
    return;
```

Comment: Hello @Lucan, it has all worked well except : if(! Block.isEqualTo(blockStateBelow.getBlock(), randomBlock )) Error : The method isEqualTo(Block, Block) is undefined for the type Block... I tried for a while to fix the error message, but didn't get it. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of Forge are you using?

Comment: @Kelbig I've updated my answer with the changes for 1.15.2, .2 because that's what I already had set up. Forge's documentation is lacking but it likely won't be too different from .1